# What is the best way to test log4js daily rollout logs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, logging

I have included log4js for logging the application in my nodejs project. I wanted to create a log file daily. I set the backup files to keep for 2 days. So I added the below configuration.

```
{
"appenders": {
  "app": {
    "type": "dateFile",
    "filename": "logs/app.log",
    "pattern": "yyyy-MM-dd",
    "daysToKeep": 2,
    "timezoneOffset" : "1m",
    "keepFileExt": true
  },
  "errorFile": {
    "type": "dateFile",
    "filename": "logs/errors.log",
    "pattern": "yyyy-MM-dd",
    "daysToKeep": 2,
    "timezoneOffset" : "1m",
    "keepFileExt": true
  },
  "errors": {
    "type": "logLevelFilter",
    "level": "ERROR",
    "appender": "errorFile"
  }
},
"categories": {
  "default": { "appenders": [ "app", "errors" ], "level": "DEBUG" }
}
```

}

After starting the application, it created two log files. app.log and error.log. I stopped the application and renamed both files as app.2021-07-18.log and error.2021-07-18 (As it would look like already a log file for 19th July is created). Again I started the application and renamed those files as like it created on 18th July. But again after starting the application, it does not remove the logs file created on 18th July. It just created app.log and error.log.

Am I testing it wrongly, or is my configuration is wrong for the daily rollout of logs?

Comment: You set daysToKeep to 2. It should delete the file from 17th July (If today is 19th) instead ,right?

Comment: Yes. I tested on 19th. So today is considered as 19th.

Comment: Then, it should only delete the files up to 17th July but not 18th July, right? What is your problem?

Comment: Yes it should delete the files which generated on 17th july(when logs for 19th july getting rolled out. Since we set to have only 2days of backup). But it is not getting deleted. It is keeping the old files too. Consider I'm using the same config untill july 25th. Then I'm having log files generated starting from 17th july.

Answer (score 0):

Only two situations will start the delete log operation:

1. The program does not close, and the date changes.
2. When the log file is too large (>maxLogSize), when rolling .

code:
[RollingFileWriteStream](https://github.com/log4js-node/streamroller/blob/master/lib/RollingFileWriteStream.js#L241)

issue:
[dateFile appender "daysToKeep" not working](https://github.com/log4js-node/log4js-node/issues/836)

You can test using the following code:

```
const log4js = require('log4js');
const path = require('path');
log4js.configure({
  appenders: {
    cheese: {
      type: 'dateFile',
      maxLogSize: 1 * 1024,
      filename: path.resolve('logs', 'client'),
      alwaysIncludePattern: true,
      pattern: '.yyyy-MM-dd.log',
      encoding: 'utf-8',
      category: '1og_date',
      daysToKeep: 1,
    },
  },
  categories: { default: { appenders: ['cheese'], level: 'error' } },
});

export const logger = log4js.getLogger('cheese');
for (let i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
  logger.trace('Entering cheese testing');
  logger.debug('Got cheese.');
  logger.info('Cheese is Comté.');
  logger.warn('Cheese is quite smelly.');
  logger.error('Cheese is too ripe!');
  logger.fatal('Cheese was breeding ground for listeria.');
}
```